# How to write a query in XSLT2.0 using variables?

Tags: xml, perl, xslt, variables, xslt-2.0

I want to use 2 variables called SOURCE and DEST.
In that manner my perl script will use

SOURCE="Bonn";

DEST="Berlin";

Then I will call the xslt2.0 transformation from my perl script.

```
<xsl:param name="SOURCE"/>
<xsl:param name="DEST"/>

<xsl:variable name="start" select="//S[@id=$SOURCE]/T[@id=$DEST]"/>

<!--<xsl:variable name="start" select="//S[@id='Paris']/T[@id='London']"/> -->
```

It happens that I do not write correctly the line (as this xslt foes not return any rows):

```
<xsl:variable name="start" select="//S[@id=$SOURCE]/T[@id=$DEST]"/>
```

Could you kindly correct my XSLT syntax ?

Comment: Well post a minimal input document you are querying where you think the path `//S[@id=$SOURCE]/T[@id=$DEST]` should select something but does not when the parameters are set to `Bonn` respectively `Berlin`. Then we are able to decide whether your path is correct or the problem is elsewhere. Also I am curious, which XSLT 2.0 processor is usable from Perl?

Comment: This query works perfectly:                                          <xsl:variable name="start" select="//S[@id='Paris']/T[@id='London']"/>                                                    I will try to post part of the input file

Comment: @Martin Input file                                                                                                                                      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <S id="Bonn">
    <T id="Berlin">
    <attributes>
    <userSpecificInfo>this is a nice trip    </userSpecificInfo>                                                      </attributes></T>
   </S>                                                                 I am thinking that the problem comes from the quotes '    '

Comment: I am just launching the saxonica Transform.exe from system() function (Perl). If faster processor, I am interested

Comment: I think the problem is simply calling Saxon the right way, if you use the command line interface then I think you need to use e.g. `transform.exe -s:file.xml -xsl:sheet.xsl -o:result.xml SOURCE=Bonn DEST=Berlin`.

Comment: @Martin you are completely right. Thanks for your analysis. I guess I am getting tired. It was not about XSL, but a mistake in calling transform.exe in Perl. Thanks

Comment: I will post my last comment as an answer so that you can mark your question as being answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is simply calling Saxon the right way, if you use the command line interface then I think you need to use e.g. `transform.exe -s:file.xml -xsl:sheet.xsl -o:result.xml SOURCE=Bonn DEST=Berlin`.

Comment: Note for people who come here later: this answer might not extrapolate to other shells / command-line interpreters. The handling of quotes and other special characters varies considerably from one shell processor to another.